# What will be the wavefunction if I add a constant to the Potential energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, conventions

I'm referring to the 1.13 problem of Griffiths.The most surprising thing is that he hasn't even started with wavefunction with time part and there's a question regarding it which must be proved by the separation of the wavefunction which he explains in the NEXT CHAPTER

$ih\psi\frac{df(t)}{dt} = \frac{ih}{2m}f(t)\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2} - \frac{i}{h} \times (V + V_0)\psi f(t)$

dividing by $\psi f(t)$

$ \frac{df(t)}{dt} = \frac{-i}{h}(E+V_0)t$

where the solution is

$f(t) = Ce^{\frac{-i}{h}E t }e^{\frac{-i}{h}V_0t}$

So this is my explanation how the $e^{\frac{-i}{h}V_0f(t)}$ must have appeared in the solution.YES its odd that on adding a constant to the potential it doesn't add up to be the total energy but its the only possible way how I can prove this fact.

My confusion is anyways is my explanation correct? If wrong please suggest the right one

Comment: The question in the title is solved in the remainder. I see no further question here. What do you mean by: "it doesn't add up to be the total energy" . The total energy from your last expresion is correctly $E+V_0$.

Comment: I think the general solution of that dif. eq. should be $f(t) = C_1e^{\frac{-i}{\hbar}(E+V_0)t} + C_2e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}(E+V_0)t}$ and you can use the enegy operator to get the result https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_operator hope it helps.

Comment: @my2cts I mean that why is $KE + V + V_0$ = $E+V_0$

Comment: Why $V_0$ doesn't become a part of the potential energy.But im now sure that adding a constant to potential energy does not 'change' the potential energy